# LINQ JOIN different tables based on conditions

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How can I join two different tables based on a condition?

I have my query as under:

```
var myquery = from p in db.tbl1
              join q in db.tbl2 on p.field1 equals q.field1
              join r in db.tbl3 on q.field2 equals r.field2
```

Till here everything is fine, now I want to add 1 more join to a table but it should be based on a condition like:

```
if(q.field3 == 1)
    join s in db.tbl4 on q.field4 equals s.field4
 else if(q.field3 == 2)
    join s in db.tbl5 on ....
```

So basically I want to join to different tables based on the value of q.field3.

Comment: Can you provide actual data and actual "complete" queries? Trying to change the shape based on data *in* a query sounds very .. suspicious. (Although it might also be as simple as performing an aggregate join and filtering/selecting the desired columns.)

Comment: Is `s` the same type in both tables? How are you planning to make the rest of the query look if it's not?

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to conditionally join based on the value of a single row.  The idea of joining is that you're joining based off of *all* of the rows.  Conditionally determining what/how to join based on some value outside of the query would make sense.

What you *can* do is do both joins unconditionally, but choose which result to use conditionally for each row.  Obviously this will only work if the tables are of the same type, or if you first project `s1` and `s2` into a common type (using `let`)

```
var myquery = from p in db.tbl1
    join q in db.tbl2 on p.field1 equals q.field1
    join r in db.tbl3 on q.field2 equals r.field2
    join s1 in db.tbl4 on q.field4 equals s1.field4
    join s2 in db.tbl5 on q.field5 equals s2.field5
    let s = q.field3 == 1 ? s1 : 
            q.field3 == 2 ? s2 : null
```

This *should* be able to be translated by the query provider into a `CASE` statement.